# How to create and plot a function involving NIntegrate

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I am interested in understanding the growth of the following function for $n\geq 2$
$$I(n) = \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{ds}{s^{1-1/n}+(1-s)^{1-1/n}-1}.$$

I can explicitly compute $I(n)$ for various values of $n$ using NIntegrate

```
phi[n_, s_] = s^(1 - 1/n) + (1 - s)^(1 - 1/n) - 1;
NIntegrate[1/phi[2, s], {s, 0, 1/2}]
```

but I would like to plot this on a graph for integer values $2\leq n\leq 100$ however I am not sure how to do this in Mathematica. Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like: ``phi[n_, s_] := s^(1 - 1/n) + (1 - s)^(1 - 1/n) - 1;
i[n_] := NIntegrate[1/phi[n, s], {s, 0, 1/2}]; ListPlot[Table[{n, i[n]}, {n, 2, 200}]]``? Note, however, that there are precision issues for $n\geq 8$.

Comment: To avoid messages use `phi[n_, s_] := s^(1 - 1/n) + (1 - s)^(1 - 1/n) - 1; 
i[n_] := 
 NIntegrate[1/phi[n, s], {s, 0, 1/2}, PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 5]`

Comment: This gives an accurate table in 3.3 sec.: `data = Table[NIntegrate[1/phi[n, s], {s, 0, 1/10, 1/2},
    Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive",
      "SingularityHandler" -> {"IMT", "TuningParameters" -> 2},
      "SingularityDepth" -> 2,
      "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0,
      Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule", "Points" -> 11}},
    PrecisionGoal -> 6, WorkingPrecision -> 24],
   {n, 2, 200}];`